# junit3 create test profiles : mock vs real classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit3

I'm working on an Adroid App, so i cannot use Junit 4.
I'm using eclipse Kepler.

I've made a set of tests that are testing mock classes.

That's fine but now i would like to do this :

1) call this situation "FastMockProfile"

2) create a new profile "SlowRealProfile"

3) be able to choose (with a simple click) if want to launch my tests with "FastMockProfile" OR "SlowRealProfile".

Depending of the profile: the same tests will be runned, but tested classes will depend on the choosen profile.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way to do is to duplicate your Testclasses. The origin classes contains the mocks and the duplicates gets the real classes to test. Then you have to create two Testsuites which contains the Mocktests or the "Realtests". Choose the Testsuite to run your profile.

A better way is dependency injection, where you can choose which implementation (mock or real) of your classes should be injected, when you run your tests. There are some Frameworks like Spring or Guice for dependency injection in Java.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well duplicating code : no way for me as this is source of problems. Instead of that, i hope there is a way in eclipse to write some configuration files to choose witch methods will setup tests. I guess there is a pattern somewhere but didn't found it yet...